# How can one find where a user is looking in a Unity scene based on Head Position, Rotation, Gaze Origin and Direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine, eye-tracking

I have a Unity scene playing a 360-degree video. The user views the 360-degree video using a HTC Vive HMD with Integrated Tobii Eye Tracker. I am using Tobii prefabs to save Raw and Unity Data to an XML file. The XML file has parameters and values like Head Position, Rotation, Gaze Position, Direction etc. How can I use these to find where the user wearing the HMD is looking into the scene?

I have used Gaze Direction values from the left and right eye and plotted these using matplotlib. However, I am unable to interpret the plot for specific conditions for e.g. when the user wearing the HMD turns around to view a portion of the  360-degree video.

```
<GazeData TimeStamp="401195894372">
    <Pose Position="(-0.23225010, 0.92871360, 0.13882240)" Rotation="(0.01330298, 0.09787695, -0.00775034, 0.99507950)" Valid="True" />
    <Left>
      <GazeDirection Value="(-0.05865479, -0.19734190, 0.97857670)" Valid="True" />
      <GazeOrigin Value="(-0.03072109, 0.00550990, -0.03687405)" Valid="True" />
      <PupilDiameter Value="0.00202419" Valid="True" />
      <GazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.26945470, 0.93564700, 0.10879590)" Direction="(0.12933440, -0.22388930, 0.96599500)" Valid="True" />
    </Left>
    <Right>
      <GazeDirection Value="(0.16032410, -0.24493410, 0.95617680)" Valid="True" />
      <GazeOrigin Value="(0.03148644, 0.00550067, -0.03543135)" Valid="True" />
      <PupilDiameter Value="0.00184862" Valid="True" />
      <GazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.20816600, 0.93479980, 0.09807995)" Direction="(0.33887940, -0.27364290, 0.90015570)" Valid="True" />
    </Right>
    <CombinedGazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.23881030, 0.93522340, 0.10343790)" Direction="(0.23560470, -0.25035830, 0.93904810)" Valid="True" />
  </GazeData>
```

Comment: I would probably focus on `<CombinedGazeRayWorld Origin="(-0.23881030, 0.93522340, 0.10343790)" Direction="(0.23560470, -0.25035830, 0.93904810)" Valid="True" />` as I understand there you have given a world position as origin and a direction vector ... what else do you need?

Comment: @derHugo. After a few plots using matplotlib, for the various head and eye movements collected using Tobii prefabs, I trust this should be good enough. Many thanks for your support.